# How to proportionally increase the size of X axis which uses d3.scaleTime?

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js

For values using scaleLinear, this works just fine:

```
X = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(Data, function (d) { return d.x })*1.10])
```

Multiplication by 1.10 does exactly what I need. However, I have not figured out how to achieve the same with a time based axis:

```
  X= d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(Data, d => d.date))
```

Comment: `Date.getTime()` gives you a number, subtract the domain values, scale and add to the end value and use `new Date(value)` for the new domain end value

Comment: @rioV8 Right but that will not be proportional, if I get it right. I would need to increase always by 10%, as in the example with scale.Linear.

Comment: You have a range of numbers shifted to the right (not starting at 0), you can make the range 10% bigger if x-domain = [20,100]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by extracting the timestamp and making mathematical operations with it. However, *time* is more complex than numbers. You have to take into account February in leap years, months with 30 or 31 days, daylight saving time, etc...

As the D3 API says about the method I'll use further down:

> ...This method does not round the specified date to the interval. For example, if date is today at 5:34 PM, then d3.timeDay.offset(date, 1) returns 5:34 PM tomorrow (even if daylight saving changes!).

That being said, it's more comfortable using the D3 time methods.

**Solution**:

What you want can be achieved using [interval.offSet](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#interval_offset), which:

> Returns a new date equal to date plus step intervals.

For this to work, we first have to compute the interval between your minimum date and your maximum date.

So, supposing we have this time scale:

```js
const parser = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y");
const dates = ["17-08-2018", "14-11-2018"].map(parser);
const scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(dates);
console.log(scale.domain())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Let's add 10% more days at the end date (you can do the same with seconds, minutes, hours, years etc...).

First, we get the number of days with [interval.count](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#interval_count):

```js
const parser = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y");
const dates = ["17-08-2018", "14-11-2018"].map(parser);
const numberOfDays = d3.timeDay.count(dates[0], dates[1]);
console.log(numberOfDays);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Then, let's multiply it by 10%:

```js
const parser = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y"); 
const percent = 0.1;
const dates = ["17-08-2018", "14-11-2018"].map(parser);
const increase = d3.timeDay.count(dates[0], dates[1]) * percent;
console.log(increase);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Don't mind about the number not being an integer: it will be floored.

Finally, we use `interval.Offset` to increase the last date:

```js
const parser = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y");
const percent = 0.1;
const dates = ["17-08-2018", "14-11-2018"].map(parser);
const increase = d3.timeDay.count(dates[0], dates[1]) * percent;
const scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([dates[0], d3.timeDay.offset(dates[1], increase)]);
console.log(scale.domain())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```